# C: Integer expression is required in switch instead of XY

Tags: c, pointers, enums, switch-statement, structure

I have a small problem with switch and structure.

I have an enum of all instructions. This recond in storaged in Instr struct (with the 3 pointers on node adress- as a three adress code)

```
typedef enum {
    // BUILT-IN FUNCTIONS
    insIfj16readInt,
    insIfj16readDouble,
    insIfj16readString,
    insIfj16lenght,
    insIfj16substr,
    insIfj16compare,
    insIfj16find,
    insIfj16sort,
    insIfj16print,
    //
    // MATH
    insPlus, 
    insMinus, 
    insMux, 
    insDiv, 
    //
    //COMPARE
    insEqual, 
    insNotEqual, 
    insLess, 
    insLessOrEqual, 
    insGreater, 
    insGreaterOrEqual, 
    insAssignment,
    insFunctionCall
}InstrType;

typedef struct Instr {
    BTSNode *Id1; 
    BTSNode *Id2; 
    BTSNode *Id3;
    InstrType *type;
}Instr;
```

But now, the compiler started complaining about switch values.

Switch code is like this:

```
instrStack *instrStack;
    // Pointer on instruction
    struct Instr *instruction;
    // Taking the first instruction from the instruction stack
    instruction = instrStackTop(instrStack);

    while(instruction != NULL) {
        instruction = instrStackTop(instrStack);

        switch (instruction->type) {
            // BUILT-IN FUNCTIONS

            case  insIfj16readInt:
                if(instruction->Id3->inc == 1) {
                    if (instruction->Id3->data.type == var_int) {
                        instruction->Id3->data.value.intValue = readInt();

                    } else {
                        throwException(4,0,0);
                    }

                } else {
                    throwException(8, 0, 0);
                }
                break;
            case insIfj16readString:

         etc. etc. more code and so one.
```

So here is the compiler complain:

> **"Integer expression is required in switch instead of 'InstrType *'**

I really don't know why is this happening. I'm using same "system" with switch and enum on my lexical analyzer (I just changing states of automat) and there is no problem with this.

Comment: Like the compiler says, `instruction->type` -> `*instruction->type`. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `instruction->type` is of type `InstrType *`. You need one more level of dereference.

Something like

```
 switch ( *(instruction->type) )
```

should do the job.

Comment: Oh It did. Thank you so much!

Comment: I strongly suspect that will result in a `SIGSEGV` as I doubt the code actually allocates memory for `instruction->type` and likely does something like `instruction->type = insIfj16readInt;`

Comment: @AndrewHenle while you may be right, that's the discussion for another post then, is not it? As per the code _shown here_, this should be solving OP's issue.

Comment: @SouravGhosh True.  You've answered the OPs question and solved the immediate problem.  I just suspect there's *more* to come, hence my comment.

Comment: @John You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062). :)

Answer (score 3):

You're a `InstrType *` (i.e. a pointer) in a context where a integer type is expected (which an `enum` is), which is not valid.

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm betting that the `type` field likely doesn't need a pointer to a `InstrType` (i.e. a `InstrType *`), just a `InstrType`.

```
typedef struct Instr {
    BTSNode *Id1; 
    BTSNode *Id2; 
    BTSNode *Id3;
    InstrType type;
}Instr;
```

Comment: This is also what I was thinking.